# No known class method for selector 'didReceiveNotificationResponse:' IOS Notifications

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, appdelegate

I've been trying to setup notifications on an IOS app for several days and I'm facing many issues.

One that i cannot figure out how it happens is the following :

In `appDelegate.m` :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Fp3.png)

I do not understand the error given the fact that I'm a React-native developper but it seems really strange.

Here is my full AppDelegate.m File :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>



#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>




static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([url.path isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
    NSString *fixedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://?%@", url.scheme, url.query];  //Pour solve l'issue suivante : https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7468
    NSURL *fixedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fixedString];
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:fixedURL options:options];
  }

  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"xxxxxx"]; // add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console


#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"Villeo"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  
  
  // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center =
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
  
  
  return YES;
}

// Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
     willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
       withCompletionHandler:
           (void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))
               completionHandler {
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge |
                  UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
[RNCPushNotificationIOS
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler
// after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        fetchCompletionHandler:
            (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
[RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
                              fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
[RNCPushNotificationIOS
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
    didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
             withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  completionHandler();
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

I've followed the best I could the setup instructions from : https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios#augment-appdelegate

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your minimum ios target set to for your project?  That method is only available after iOS 10

Comment: My minimum iOS target is set to 10.0